# CSS animations not working for safari or opera

Tags: css, animation, safari, opera

I have a problem getting the animations on my site to work for safari and opera. I've used all the prefixes everywhere and I've researched about this a lot to make sure my code is correct, however there must be something I am still missing. Please, look at code below and give me some advice on how to proceed.

```
@-webkit-keyframes moves {
from {
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    } to {
    transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -o-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    }}
@-moz-keyframes moves {
from {
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    } to {
    transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -o-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    }}
@-o-keyframes moves {
from {
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    } to {
    transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -o-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    }}
@keyframes moves {
from {
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -o-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    } to {
    transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -o-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    }}
```

This is how I call my animations:

```
    .move {
-webkit-animation: moves 4s 2.5s forwards;
-moz-animation:    moves 4s 2.5s forwards;
-o-animation:    moves 4s 2.5s forwards;
animation:    moves 4s 2.5s forwards;}
```

Finally, I call these animations on document load with Jquery by adding this class to the desired div or section.

Problem is, my animations work perfectly with mozilla and chrome,only partially with opera, and almost none of my animations work in safari.
Oh, also my document load Jquery doesn't seem to be working for Opera - it is just starting the animations that do work before the full page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me in Safari and Chrome right now (don't feel like downloading Opera atm). You're using a lot of vendor prefixes in areas where you only need one ^_^  :

https://jsfiddle.net/JTBennett/egfw1392/

```
@keyframes moves {
from {
    transform: translate(0px,0px);
    } to {
    transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    }}
@-webkit-keyframes moves {
from {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    } to {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    }}
@-moz-keyframes moves {
from {
    -moz-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    } to {
    -moz-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    }}
@-o-keyframes moves {
from {
    -o-transform: translate(0px,0px);
    } to {
    -o-transform: translate(-45%, -100%);
    }}
@-ms-keyframes moves {
    from {
        -ms-transform: translate(0,0);
    } to {
        -ms-transform: translate(-45%,-100%);
    }}




.moves {
-webkit-animation: moves 4s 2.5s forwards;
-moz-animation:    moves 4s 2.5s forwards;
-o-animation:    moves 4s 2.5s forwards;
animation:    moves 4s 2.5s forwards;}
```

Then just assign your class to desired element.
Hope that solves everything!

-Joel

Comment: Thank you for your efforts Joel!

Comment: Did you get it working? If you want to guarantee it functions on all browsers and devices, we can make a jQuery script to perform this animation. It'd actually be a lot smaller too - if you want, I can put it on jsfiddle for you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/JTBennett/tazw1m4y/13/

^This is the jQuery code for the same animation - no compatibility issues/vendor prefixes with this. Let me know if you need any more help with it.

Comment: I got it to work. Thank you for your comments, they helped